# Please check why ubuntu is giving error

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, vim, make

code:

```
char index2key(u64 index, char* key, u32 l_min, u32 l_max, const char* charset, u32 n_charset)
{
        u32 l_key = l_min;
        u64 n_key = pow(n_charset, l_min);
        while (index >= n_key)
        {
                index -= n_key;
                n_key *= n_charset;
                l_key++;
        }
        if (l_key > l_max)
                return 0;

        for (u32 i = 0; i < l_key; i++, key++)
        {
                *key = charset[index % n_charset];
                index /= n_charset;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

Error in the when I build with docker:

```
Step 5/8 : RUN apt-get install -y build-essential git vim
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6922ee2f0d9d
Step 6/8 : COPY * /build/
 ---> 4ba9cf1a6281
Step 7/8 : RUN  make
 ---> Running in 6d369aa32323
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic -std=c99 -O3 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -g -c rtgen.c -o rtgen.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic -std=c99 -O3 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -g -c md5.c -o md5.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic -std=c99 -O3 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -g -c rtable.c -o rtable.o
gcc -O3 -lm -lpthread rtgen.o md5.o rtable.o -o rtgen
/usr/bin/ld: rtable.o: in function `index2key':
/build/rtable.c:249: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /build/rtable.c:249: undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:10: rtgen] Error 1
rm rtgen.o rtable.o md5.o
The command '/bin/sh -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: This is likely nothing to do with Ubuntu - it's the order in which you are linking object code files and libraries. See for example [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: Likely problem: `pow()` requires inclusion of  `math.h` and linking against a relevant maths lib.